# How many addressed can be added to a bitcoin full node?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, bitcoin, json-rpc, bitcore

I'm running a Bitcoin full node on my server.
I'm going to use this server as a light wallet api server using RCP methods.
And I'm going to add an address to the node whenever a light wallet generates a new address to track all transactions and unspent outputs of the address.

And I'm wondering how many addresses can be added to a full node?

Is it limitless or is there a maximum number?

And does the number of addresses added to the node affect the performance of the node?

And for some reason I can't use addressindex feature of bitcore, so I'm going to use importaddress, listunspent and listtransactions methods.

Comment: When you say bitcore, do you mean Bitcoin Core?

Comment: Similar question was asked few years ago. There is no actual limit for number addresses and  tens of millions of addresses do not affect performance. Take a look https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/24947/what-is-the-maximum-of-receive-addresses-the-default-wallet-can-handle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no software limit. The system is limited by disk space, used for the file wallet.dat. Practically, wallet.dat can contain 300,000 addresses, or even more.